# Executing mount command in Android device via application

Tags: java, android, mount

I have already rooted my emulator android device and now want to execute the following system call:

> mount -o rw,remount /system

My code is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su -c mount -o rw,remount /system" );
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{"su", "-c", "mount -o remount,rw /system"} );
```

Try this as well:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{"su", "-c", "mount -o remount rw /system"} );
```

Also, you need the following permission in your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
```

Comment: Thank you again Ankur Aggarwal for your help. I tried with String array with the following command:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{"su", "-c", "mount", "-o", "rw,remount /system"} );

but didn't work.

Comment: Mount, -o and the rest of the command should not be separated by "". "mount -o remount rw /system" MUST be a single command in string array. I edited my answer. Try that again